# Python library to split and join mp3 files

Tags: python, mp3

There are a lot of libs to work with mp3 tags, but I need just 2 functions - split mp3 file in 2 parts and the second one to merge 5 mp3.

Can you suggest anything?
Thanks!

Comment: When you join mp3 files you will find a gap between them, because mp3 is block based and the last block of a file will be filled with silence.

Answer (score 149):

I wrote a library ([pydub](http://pydub.com)) for pretty much this exact use case:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("/path/to/file.mp3")

# len() and slicing are in milliseconds
halfway_point = len(sound) / 2
second_half = sound[halfway_point:]

# Concatenation is just adding
second_half_3_times = second_half + second_half + second_half

# writing mp3 files is a one liner
second_half_3_times.export("/path/to/new/file.mp3", format="mp3")
```

### Adding a silent gap

If you'd like to add silence between parts of a sound:

```
two_sec_silence = AudioSegment.silent(duration=2000)
sound_with_gap = sound[:1000] + two_sec_silence + sound[1000:]
```

Comment: @Jiaaro is it possible to create a pause of 2seconds between two files ?

Comment: @발렌텐 yes, just create a silent audio segment: `two_sec_pause = AudioSegment.silent(duration=2000)` which you can then concatenate like normal `sound1 + two_sec_pause + sound2`

Comment: this lib is a gem, thanks for your share, this is very helping, I am developping a software for language learners giving them the opportunity to generate training sounds made from spoken-word short mp3 files.

Comment: Cool and easy to use! (Off-topic I like your blog:-)

Comment: Really nice! I came here after struggling with `mp3wrap` etc: nothing more efficient and simple than this `pydub`! The result is clean, the duration of a concatenated file to be exported is correct, the name is easy to set... And easy to install for `anaconda`: https://anaconda.org/auto/pydub. @Jiaaro would there by any chance be a tool to slow down a file (i.e., change the tempo)?

Comment: Does this library avoid re-encoding?

Comment: @andresp no, it decodes when you open and re-encodes when you export. Most types of changes aren't possible without re-encoding (especially when you are working with multiple audio inputs, which may not have matching formats/channels/bitrate/encoder settings/etc)

Comment: I know. I was just asking if it avoided it when it's not needed (e.g. concatenate two files with the same format, like mp3cat can do). Thanks for the response!

Comment: @Jiaaro would like to ask how to use this library in Function as a Service (FaaS) but prefer not to open a thread. So, I have to include a static build of ffmpeg?

Comment: @Jun you need either ffmpeg or avlib if you want to do format conversions. WAVE format is supported in pure python. To open or save other formats you will need one of those packages installed

Comment: without streams it runs out of memory easily

Comment: @Curcuma_ That's true, so far nobody has contributed a lazy or streaming implementation of AudioSegment. For long audio clips it's sometimes problematic

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at the [MP3 file structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mp3#File_structure) on Wikipedia.  Use binary read mode in python to edit the MP3 file.  `s = open(file_name, 'rb').read()` will put the whole file into a string object representing the raw bytes in your file (e.g. `\xeb\xfe\x80`).  You can then search and edit the string, addressing the byte offsets with indices using brackets: `s[n]`.  Finally, just do a binary write of the MP3 frames you want in your new file(s), appending the ID3 header to the set of frames that you want to make up each file.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my attempt at splitting an MP3 using python without re-encoding. Not all varieties of MP3 files are supported and I would gladly welcome suggestions or improvements. The script is hard coded to split at 55 seconds but the code demonstrates the general principles.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import struct
import sys

#MP3 frames are not independent because of the byte reservoir. This script does not account for
#that in determining where to do the split.

def SplitMp3(fi, splitSec, out):

    #Constants for MP3
    bitrates = {0x0: "free", 0x1: 32, 0x2: 40, 0x3: 48, 0x4: 56, 0x5: 64, 0x6: 80, 0x7: 96, 0x8: 112,
        0x9: 128, 0xa: 160, 0xb: 192, 0xc: 224, 0xd: 256, 0xe: 320, 0xf: "bad"}
    freqrates = {0x0: 44100, 0x1: 48000, 0x2: 32000, 0x3: "reserved"}
    countMpegFrames = 0
    frameDuration = 0.026
    unrecognizedBytes = 0
    splitFrame = int(round(splitSec / frameDuration))

    while True:

        startPos = fi.tell()

        #Check for 3 byte headers
        id3Start = fi.read(3)
        if len(id3Start) == 3:

            if id3Start == b'TAG':
                print ("Found ID3 v1/1.1 header")
                fi.seek(startPos + 256)
                continue

            if id3Start == b'ID3':
                #Possibly a ID3v2 header
                majorVer, minorVer, flags, encSize = struct.unpack(">BBBI", fi.read(7))
                if majorVer != 0xFF and minorVer != 0xFF:
                    encSize1 = (encSize & 0x7f000000) >> 24
                    encSize2 = (encSize & 0x7f0000) >> 16
                    encSize3 = (encSize & 0x7f00) >> 8
                    encSize4 = (encSize & 0x7f)
                    if encSize1 < 0x80 and encSize2 < 0x80 and encSize3 < 0x80 and encSize4 < 0x80:
                        size = ((encSize & 0x7f000000) >> 3) + ((encSize & 0x7f0000) >> 2) + ((encSize & 0x7f00) >> 1) + (encSize & 0x7f)
                        unsync = (flags >> 7) & 0x1
                        extendedHeader = (flags >> 6) & 0x1
                        experimental = (flags >> 5) & 0x1
                        print ("Found ID3v2 header")
                        print ("version", majorVer, minorVer, unsync, extendedHeader, experimental)
                        print ("size", size)
                        #TODO extendedHeader not supported yet

                        fi.seek(startPos + 10 + size)
                        continue

        #Check for 4 byte headers
        fi.seek(startPos)
        headerRaw = fi.read(4)
        if len(headerRaw) == 4:
            headerWord = struct.unpack(">I", headerRaw)[0]

            #Check for MPEG-1 audio frame
            if headerWord & 0xfff00000 == 0xfff00000:
                print ("Possible MPEG-1 audio header", hex(headerWord))
                countMpegFrames += 1
                ver = (headerWord & 0xf0000) >> 16
                bitrateEnc = (headerWord & 0xf000) >> 12
                freqEnc = (headerWord & 0xf00) >> 8
                mode = (headerWord & 0xf0) >> 4
                cpy = (headerWord & 0xf)
                if ver & 0xe == 0xa and freqEnc != 0xf:
                    print ("Probably an MP3 frame")
                    bitrate = bitrates[bitrateEnc]
                    freq = freqrates[freqEnc >> 2]
                    padding = ((freqEnc >> 1) & 0x1) == 1
                    print ("bitrate", bitrate, "kbps")
                    print ("freq", freq, "Hz")
                    print ("padding", padding)
                    frameLen = int((144 * bitrate * 1000 / freq ) + padding)

                    #Copy frame to output
                    fi.seek(startPos)
                    frameData = fi.read(frameLen)
                    if countMpegFrames >= splitFrame:
                        out.write(frameData)

                    fi.seek(startPos + frameLen)
                    continue
                else:
                    raise RuntimeError("Unsupported format:", hex(ver), "header:", hex(headerWord))

        #If no header can be detected, move on to the next byte
        fi.seek(startPos)
        nextByteRaw = fi.read(1)
        if len(nextByteRaw) == 0:
            break #End of file
        unrecognizedBytes += 1

    print ("unrecognizedBytes", unrecognizedBytes)
    print ("countMpegFrames", countMpegFrames)
    print ("duration", countMpegFrames * frameDuration, "sec")

if __name__=="__main__":
    fi = open(sys.argv[1], "rb")
    out = open("test.mp3", "wb")
    SplitMp3(fi, 55.0, out)
    out.close()
```

Merging would be a similar case of extracting and appending frames from two separate MP3 input files.

Comment: If you want want to trim the audio, modify the code by adding another parameter to denote the ending time (say `secondSplitSec`). Calculate `secondSplitFrame` by using a similar formula to that of `splitFrame`. Change `if countMpegFrames >= splitFrame:` to `if secondSplitFrame >= countMpegFrames >= splitFrame:`

Comment: I have wanted to trim the audio , and I edited the code as aronquemarr(upper comment) told . I have succesfully splitted the long mp3 file but it was too loosy . For instance I splitted 0 to 41 second of audio , it splitted 0 to 37 and that loosieness is increasing with amount . I researched a little bit , but I couldn't find the reason

Answer (score 3):

Check out [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) and its Python wrapper [Gst-Python](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html).

Answer (score -4):

use the unix split command:

```
split -b 200k file.mp3 output_
```

this will output output_a, output_b, output_c, ..

you can then get mp3 files just by renaming

```
for file in ./output_*; do mv "$file" "$(basename $file).mp3"; done
```

this will output output_a.mp3, output_b.mp3, output_c.mp3 ... all of them (except the last one, may be) are 200kb in size, and the total size of the output_x is the same as file.mp3

you can use the `du` (disk usage) command to get the file's number of byte and then decide how many bytes to cut..

```
du -sh file.mp3
```

then to join use the cat command:

```
cat output_2.mp3 output_3.mp3 output_4.mp3 > output.mp3
```

of course you can put all this in a shell script and call it from python.

Comment: You won't be able to play such segments.

Comment: The comment is useful, however, splitting the audio is something completely different from splitting the binary structure of the file.