# how to join multiple audio files (MP3) into one with python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a music maker in python,
if you can help I will be grateful

I want to attach multiple audio files (MP3) into one with python
and then export it to a mp3 file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python library to split and join mp3 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952309/python-library-to-split-and-join-mp3-files)